# unable to checkout with paypal express when using a discount code

Tags: magento-1, error, paypal, discount, promotions

never seen this problem before on any other website but when we try to checkout via paypal express when trying to use a discount code we get an error

Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.(`10413`)

I enabled paypal logging but the long message just says:

> The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

I have checked the magento configuration but I can't see anywhere I can remove this check like I can with other payment providers, any advice?

**Theres an option to transfer cart line items over to paypal but that's set to "no"**

please help.

Comment: Change that product price for testing and check again.

Comment: tried all sorts of products it's not product specific, im thinking it could be something to do with tax? I know there's a really old issue with magento calculations with tax vs paypal calculation?

Comment: Try my solution and check again

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom module

Create an observer

```
        <paypal_prepare_line_items>
            <observers>
                <your_customdiscount_paypal_prepare_line_items>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Your_Customdiscount_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addDiscountToPayPal</method>
                </your_customfee_paypal_prepare_line_items>
            </observers>
        </paypal_prepare_line_items>
```

Here is the function to add to the observer:

```
  public function addDiscountToPayPal($observer) {

        $paypalCart = $observer->getPaypalCart();

        if ($paypalCart) {
            $order = $paypalCart->getSalesEntity();
            $discountAmount = $order->getDiscountAmount();
            $paypalCart->updateTotal(Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart::TOTAL_DISCOUNT, $discountAmount);

        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will try this and see if it works for us.